# Compare two dates when testing with mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am using `"chai": "^4.2.0"` and `"mocha": "^6.1.4",`.

When using `assert.equal()` to compare two dates I get false even though these two dates seem to be the same:

[image]

Here is my example test:

```
  it('check if dates are correctly added', async () => {
let dataArr = [{'rating_date':'6/6/2019','impact_on_price':'Low'}]   
let priceServ = new PriceService()

// clear all records
priceServ.clearPriceTable()

// add 1 record
const res = await priceServ.createOrUpdatePrice(dataArr)

// get "all" records from the table that have a certain action attribute
const tableValues = await priceServ.getPricesByField('rating_date')
assert.equal(tableValues[0].rating_date, new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date));
```

});

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `assert.equal` checks for strict equality, however you're passing two different date instances (it doesn't matter that they refer to the same date).

Comment: @Jb31 Thx for your reply! How can I assess if the date is the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chai's [`assert.deepEqual`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#deepequalactual-expected-message) compares `Date` objects correctly.

```js
const { assert } = require('chai')

const a = new Date(0)
const b = new Date(0)
const c = new Date(1)

assert.deepEqual(a, b) // ok
assert.deepEqual(b, c) // throws
```

Of course it is necessary that both arguments passed to `deepEqual` are `Date` objects, not `string`s or `number`s.

Comment: This doesn't work. It has sub-millisecond skew.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to import `expect` rather than `assert`. You can then use Chai's deep equality check `.eql()`, ex:

```
  expect.eql(tableValues[0].rating_date, new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date));
```

I prefer this approach as failure messages are logged as plain dates making it easier to fix the failing test.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment, `assert.equal` checks for strict equality. Try comparing the timestamps instead:

```
assert.equal(tableValues[0].rating_date.getTime(), new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date).getTime());
```

Note that the error messages can be quite ugly when the dates aren't the same. There are [libraries](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-datetime/) for that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a plugin called chai-datetime. https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-datetime/

Require

```
const chai = require("chai");
const assert = chai.assert;
chai.use(require("chai"));
```

Import

```
import chai, { assert } from "chai";
import chaiDateTime from "chai-datetime";
chai.use(chaiDateTime);
```

```
// old
assert.equal(tableValues[0].rating_date, new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date));

// with plugin
// compares only the date portion
assert.equalDate(tableValues[0].rating_date, new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date));
// compares timestamps
assert.equalTime(tableValues[0].rating_date, new Date(dataArr[0].rating_date));

// Also!
let date1 = new Date();
let date2 = date1.toISOString();
let date3 = date1.valueOf();
let date4 = date1.getTime();

assert.equalTime(date1, date1);
assert.equalTime(date1, date2);
assert.equalTime(date1, date3);
assert.equalTime(date1, date4);
assert.equalTime(date2, date1);
assert.equalTime(date2, date2);
assert.equalTime(date2, date3);
assert.equalTime(date2, date4);
// and so on.
// There are also other assertions added, such as before-, closeTo-, afterOrEqual-, within-, etc.

let date5 = new Date();
assert.afterOrEqual(date5, date1);
assert.closeTo(date5, date2, 5) // delta = within 5 seconds
```

Note: I find it more useful to compare timestamps when testing.  It's easier to test that way.  I was working on a Java api connected to a MSSQL server, with a JS frontend.  On my local version, saving birthdates and training dates worked fine.  When my supervisor connected to the live dev server, every time she saved a form, every date would be moved backwards by one day.  That's because it was considering the time at midnight and the timezone got mixed up or something.  So JS would convert the day to a datetime at midnight, send it up, and Java would send back a datetime at midnight in another timezone, which was on the previous day.  I ended up setting everything to noon, because the timezone difference was less than twelve hours.